# How to stop a Timer (util) with a while loop in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, timer, timertask

**Description:** I am trying to stop the timer from running once i=10 with a while loop.  This is only a test. In my project, I am actually going to use the timer to check a boolean value from an online database and stop the timer once "*true*" is returned.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer ran for:" + ++i);
        }
    };

    while (i < 10) {
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Timer ran for:1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled
    at java.base/java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:402)
    at java.base/java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:249)
    at Code.testUtilTimer.main(testUtilTimer.java:31)
Timer ran for:2
Timer ran for:3
Timer ran for:4
Timer ran for:5
Timer ran for:6
Timer ran for:7
Timer ran for:8
Timer ran for:9
Timer ran for:10
Timer ran for:11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you don't need to use while loop. Already schedule will work at certain time intervals. If you do as in my example, you will solve your problem.

```
 TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            boolean dbValue = //Database operations
            if(dbValue) {
              cancel();
            }
           
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
    
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000L, 1000L);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating multiple time schedulers that's why the exception.

You should create once the scheduled task (running for every X time) and wait.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        int i = 0;

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (++i > 5) {
                timer.cancel(); // no more times
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Timer ran for:" + i);
            }
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 0, 500);

    System.out.println("waiting for all tasks completion...");
}
```

with output

```
waiting for all tasks completion...
Timer ran for:1
Timer ran for:2
Timer ran for:3
Timer ran for:4
Timer ran for:5

Process finished with exit code 0
```